# How can I run Gradle+Tomcat with remote debugger inside IntelliJ in a single build step?

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, gradle, remote-debugging

I have a Gradle project that uses [Gradle Tomcat plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-tomcat-plugin). Since the project is running on Tomcat, I have to use Java's remote debugger to connect to the server. So in steps what I do now is that:

1. Run Gradle build with remote debugger
2. Run Remote Debugger that connect's to the Tomcat

The question is: is it possible to run Gradle build with Tomcat from inside IntelliJ without having two separate build steps?

I already tried adding the Gradle build to "Before launch" step to Remote debugger:

[image: Remote debugger with tomcatRun in before launch (doesn't work)]

But this doesn't work since tomcatRun never gets completed and so the remote debugger is never executed.

Comment: When you start the debugger in IntelliJ, do you see a message telling you that it connected to your application?  (I have dealt with similar issues in IntelliJ before)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: The remote debugger works and I get the message ("Connected to the target VM..."), but only if I run it in a separate tab. With "before launch" configuration it doesn't work since tomcatRun never completes. So the question here is strictly: is it possible to somehow run remote debugger *and* tomcat in a same build step?

Comment: Can you run Tomcat in _non_ debugging mode from the dialog box?  Are you sure that Tomcat is listening on port 5005 for the debugger (this is an unusual port number from what I can tell).

Comment: I can run Tomcat in non debugging mode if its running in another build target. So it works regardless of what mode is it in. The port numbers are assigned correctly. I don't have any trouble at all running the debugger if I split it into two separate steps (tomcatRun in first tab, remote debugger in second).

Comment: I'm out of bullets then.  The only other thing which comes to mind would be to try checking Tomcat's logs for some sort of error being thrown.  If there is no trace of anything in the logs, then you might question whether you are really connecting to it at all.

Comment: Yeah thanks for your help so far! As I wrote: the problem is that I haven't figured out a way that allows me to run tomcat somehow in "background" - the remote debugger never starts if I run tomcat in its "before launch" step.

Comment: You never answered my question though.  What are the logs showing you?

Comment: Tomcat logs are clean (no errors).

Comment: I'm prepared to be wrong, but this seems to be that IntelliJ is never actually talking to Tomcat.  So the failure could be upstream.

Comment: You are 100% right. As I wrote in the question, the remote debugger never gets started. And thats exactly the issue here: how could I run tomcat in a way that it would allow me to execute the remote debugger in the same build task?

Answer (score 0):

run this in cmd

```
set GRADLE_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=5005,server=y,suspend=n
```

run this command in cmd

```
gradle tomcatRun
```

and then start remote application as mentioned in questions diagram